# Simple NPM package bundling/vendoring?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Disclaimer: I am primarely a backend developer with no extensive FE knowledge.

I am writing a non-SPA Golang web application that generates HTML, which is then sent to the user.
Because I'd like to update and monitor my Javascript/CSS dependencies better, I want to switch to using NPM with a `package.json` file instead of manually downloading and appending CSS and Javascript libraries. These are the typical jquery, bootstrap and fontawesome.
In addition to this, I have a single Javascript file per page for interactive content.

e.g.

```
+ js
  lib.js    -> jquery, bootstrap, fontawesome
  - home    -> specific JS
  - account -> specific JS
  ...
+ css
  theme.css
  custom.css
```

However, I see no simple solution to just `npm install` and export the installed packages to a `vendor.js` file, minified.
Iv'e looked at webpack ([go-webpack](https://github.com/go-webpack/webpack)), but this horribly complex with the whole tree shaking, bundling and shimming. In addition, webpack expects you to run a development server when serving assets locally, do some chunk magic and still refer to global libraries in every JS file. (to prevent from being tree-shaken away)

Is there an easier way to go from a `package.json` file to a minified, bundled set of assets?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  There are alternatives to webpack that you may want to look into one.  One popular one is browserify.  It's not quite as magical as webpack, but it may be all you need and is considerably more straightforward.  You will undoubtedly get a tonne of other suggestions, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: *‘You can’t see the forest for the trees’* - Just get a minimal configuration of `webpack.config.js` working before diving into more advanced details, such as tree shaking, chunking, etc...

You need to use a bundler, such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), to bundle all your `JavaScript` assets into a single `JavaScript` file. I think you're trying to do too much to start with:

- [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)
- Tree Shaking
- Chunking

As these are more advanced concepts... Perhaps you could start by initially *creating a single `JavaScript` bundle (or a bundle on a per page basis) to be used by your application*. This wouldn't be as complex and would require  entry points into the following files within your application:

1. Application's `JavaScript` index (This should load the `JavaScript` used by your application)
2. `CSS` index. (Ideally, you have a root styling file which loads other application styling files)

Now set-up the appropriate loaders and plugins for your application's assets, such as the `MiniCssExtractPlugin`, `file-loader`, etc..., to load and handle your applications' assets. Once everything is working, simply attach this generated bundle in a `<script>` tag within your root `html` index page, rather than initially configuring a `webpack-dev-server`. This will allow your application to use your bundled `JavaScript` file without the need to configure a `webpack-dev-server.` To create new bundles create custom commands within the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file, something along the lines of:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
```

**Only after everything is working should you worry about more advanced performance gains**, such as: chunking/treeshaking/etc... Take a look at the following tutorials as they may help: [Intro to Webpack](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-beginners-guide-to-webpack-4-a8cade06f092) and [Full Stack Web application](https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9). Note the second tutorial is a little dated as the defacto now would be to use `create-react-app` cli instead of setting up the build configurations yourself for a `react` project, *BUT the principles are sound and show you how to go about setting up your own build configuration.*

Hopefully that helps!